# Secure Connection with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, ssl, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking for a webservice call. I need to show an error  if i call a request url that is  untrusted. I am using below code with a untrusted request URL, still it calls the success task with information. I need to restrict it.

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
 operation.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = NO;
```

Comment: What makes a request URL untrusted?

Comment: if the sever certificate is expired

Comment: What version of AFNetworking are you using? Are you using SSL pinning? Did you make sure the URL has the "https" scheme set?

Comment: I am not using pinning, I need to make sure server request url is secure

Comment: Please answer my other questions.

Comment: Afnetworking 2.0 , URL has the "https" scheme

Comment: A number of security bugs have been fixed since then. Can you upgrade to AFNetworking 2.5.3?